# How to access child list data and return in a function in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a new function and I am passing Firebase snapshots stream as `streamFinal` variable passed in function:

```
Future<List<ChatMessage>> _prepareListData(streamFinal) {
    List<ChatMessage> msgList = [];
    int counter = 0;
    // objects map
    streamFinal.map((event) {
      // documents map
      event.docs.map((item) {
        Map<String, dynamic> uData = item.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        ChatMessage messageInfo = ChatMessage(
          encMessageId: uData['encMessageId'] ?? "",
          encSenderUId: uData['encSenderUId'] ?? "",
          encReceiverUId: uData['encReceiverUId'] ?? "",
          contentType: uData['contentType'] ?? "",
          fileType: uData['fileType'] ?? "",
          fileTitle: uData['fileTitle'] ?? "",
          filename: uData['filename'] ?? "",
          fileSize: uData['fileSize'] ?? "",
          fileDuration: uData['fileDuration'] ?? "",
          message: uData['message'] ?? "",
          sentOn: uData['sentOn'] ?? Timestamp.now(),
          seenOn: uData['seenOn'] ?? Timestamp.now(),
          sent: uData['sent'] ?? false,
          received: uData['received'] ?? false,
          seen: uData['seen'] ?? false,
        );
        msgList.add(messageInfo);
        counter = counter +1;
        print("counter: $counter");
        // printing counter from 1 to 19 means we have 19 records of messageInfo variable
      }).toList();
    }).toList();

    print('prepare msgList length: ${msgList.length} == $counter');
    // prepare msgList length: 0 == 0

    return msgList;
  }
```

This function is returning me a blank List with null elements while counter is being printed 19 times. I know I have 19 records but not able to add all `messageInfo` in `msgList` variable.

Is there anyone who has such experience and help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: why is there everywhere `async`? I don't see any async code

Comment: why are you having list inside another list

Comment: @Shrirakshabhat I am merging two `Streams` into one `Stream` then pass output to this function eg. `Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamFinal = StreamGroup.merge([streamOne, streamTwo]);` then `_messagessList = await _prepareListData(streamFinal) as List<ChatMessage>;` thats why need to run `streamFinal.map((event) {` because it has 2 Stream typed objects and first `Stream object` has 10 documents and second `Stream object` has 9 documents. I want output of this function as 19 records. Kindly check it and suggest me, what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks a lot.